# Type hinting and checking in python inheritance - overloading methods and accepting different arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I usually end up with class hierarchies like the following when designing a new component

```py
class Base(ABC):                                                                                
    """Parent."""                                                                                                  
                                                                                                         
    def __init__(self, arg0: int, *args, **kargs):  
        self._arg0 = arg0                                                        
        pass                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                         
class Child1(Base):                                                                    
    def __init__(self, arg1: str, arg2: int, arg3: float, *args, **kargs):                     
        super().__init__(*args, **kargs)                                                                 
                                                                                                         
        self._arg1 = arg1
        ...                                                                       
                                                                                                         
class Child2(Child1):                                                                    
    def __init__(self, arg4: float, *args, **kargs):                     
        super().__init__(*args, **kargs)                                                                 
                                                                                                         
        self._arg4 = arg4

...

child = Child2(arg1=..., arg2=..., arg3=..., arg4=...)
```

I like the flexibility of this approach and the fact that each class in the hierarchy receives only the arguments it's interested in and then forwards the rest.

What I don't like is that, linters, e.g. mypy, and autocompletion tools do not know of the extra arguments that the base class(es) of the one I'm instantiating are accepting and may not issue warnings/errors if I do not pass the required arguments of the parent class(es).

So in the above example, if I don't explicitly pass e.g. `arg3=3.14`, tools usually don't give errors because `arg3` is not part of the `Child2` signature but the program will still throw an exception as `Child1` is explicitly trying to access that argument.

- Is there a better approach to this?
- If not, is there a way of making these tools aware of these extra arguments?

Comment: I don't know if there is any tool that allows to do that. But I don't think it's a good idea. When you override the init method you change the positional parameters. Therefore they are no longer required. Then, the parameters with which you call the constructor of the parent class dempen from your code.